# Why are inline-level boxes not being laid out according to block formatting context rules despite being inside one?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to understand the relationship between formatting context and inner and outer display types.

On one hand, the official explanation, in W3 and related websites, says that, all boxes have a formatting context. They either create one, or continue the one of their parent, which too, either created a formatting context, or continued one of its parent, and so on until the initial block formatting context established by the HTML element.

Elements inside a block formatting context are laid out according to block formatting context rules. So that means that, when you insert a div inside another div, the child div is laid out according to the block formatting context rules, because its parent has a block formatting context rules.

So then why aren't elements with display:inline or inline-flex not being laid out according to block formatting context rules?

The explanation states that, the inner display type defines the formatting context which determines the way elements will be laid out. The outer display type dictates how the principle box participates in the flow layout.

This last explanation confuses me, because, isn't the way elements participate inside a container determined by the formatting context of that container?

When you set the display type of a div to "flex", that element creates a flex formatting context inside of itself, however, on the outside, it still behaves according to block formatting context rules, because it is inside one, is that not correct? So, then, why is the same thing not happening with inline elements, or elements with display inline-flex? Why is their outer display type not block when they are inside one?

If changing the display property changes the formatting context inside the element, while its outer behavior is determined by the formatting context of ITS parent, then why are inline elements and inline-flex elements and probably others too not being laid out according to block rules when inside a block formatting context?

Answer (score 1):

> then why are inline elements and inline-flex elements and probably others too not being laid out according to block rules when inside a block formatting context?

You are missing a small piece of the puzzle that is called [*anonymous block box*](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#anonymous-block-level)

> In other words: if a block container box (such as that generated for the DIV above) has a block-level box inside it (such as the P above), then **we force it to have only block-level boxes inside it.**

In order to force only block level boxes inside a block formatting context we put our inline elements (or inline-block ones) inside an *anonymous block box*. That anonymous box will then create an inline formatting context inside it for the inline elements.

Considering this, all the rules you have described will be accurate.